# OpenGL - find rotation vector for glRotate()

Tags: c++, c, opengl, vector, rotation

I have been working on the problem of implementing roll-, pitch-, and yaw-style rotations in OpenGL for quite some time, with limited relevant material available online. The crux of the problem is finding the updated local axes, as the object is rotating. For example, rotation around X, causes local Y and Z axes to change. Subsequent rotations will be around the updated axes. I have found some mathematical formulas to find the updated vectors here:

http://nehe.gamedev.net/article/camera_class_tutorial/18010/

However, the new vector is given in terms of points, e.g., rotation of 45 degrees around Y-axis changes the X-axis, which now passes through the points (0.71, 0, 0.71). The question now is how to find the (x, y, z) points which can be passed in to glRotatef(angle, x, y, z). Note that x, y, z, lie on a vector which passes through them and the origin.

I am thinking of taking a normal to the line passing through (0.71, 0, 0.71) and origin, and then again taking a normal to get (x, y, z).

Can anyone suggest an improvement to this, or an alternative method?

Comment: Don't make your life harder than it has to be. Rotating about the local x-axis is still a rotation about the x-axis. You just have to multiply the rotation matrix at the correct side of the current one. And that depends on whether it is a view transform or a model transform. This can be pretty ugly to achieve with `glRotate()` etc., but those functions are deprecated anyway. You should consider using a math library like glm. This gives you more flexibility and rotation about local axes comes with it for free.

Comment: @NicoSchertler: I am avoiding using glm. Would you recommend multiplying the transformation matrix, using glMultMatrixf(), for example?

Comment: That's what `glRotate` does. If that does not work for you, you have to multiply it on the other side. Store the matrix via `glGet()`. Load the identity matrix via `glLoadIdentity()`. Perform `glRotate()`. Multiply the old matrix via `glMultMatrix()`.

Comment: @NicoSchertler: However for glRotate, I'll need the updated axes, correct? On the other hand I have the transformation matrix, which I can multiply myself, and not use glRotate.

Comment: You have two options. Use `glRotate()` with the updated axes to multiply the rotation matrix on the right. Second: Use the approach above (with the default axes) to multiply the rotation matrix on the left. Btw, you get the updates axes by multiplying the matrix with the vectors `(1, 0, 0, 0)`, `(0, 1, 0, 0)` etc.

Comment: @NicoSchertler: Sorry, just to clarify: If I have transformation matrix for rotation, I do NOT need glRotate anymore? (and hence no need to find updated axes)

Comment: `glRotate()` calculates a rotation matrix and multiplies it on the right side of the current matrix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55084/discussion-between-iceman-and-nico-schertler).

Comment: So, what is the actual problem here? You have three rotation angles, correct? `pitch`, `yaw` and `roll`. All you need should be `glRotatef (pitch, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); glRotatef (yaw, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); glRotatef (roll, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);` unless I am misunderstanding something.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use quaternions. It is somewhat conceptually difficult to grasp at first, but once you get the gist of it, the implementation is quite straight-forward. Moreover, quaternion rotation allows you to avoid the gimbal lock :)

OpenGL Quaternion tutorial site:

http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/tutorial-17-quaternions/

Comment: Quaternions provide no functional feature that matrices don't provide. They might be slightly faster and numerically more stable, but in the end you have to multiply them in the correct order, just like matrices.

Comment: I'm only proposing an alternative method to the classical Euler transforms ;) Moreover, the tutorial I posted explains quite clearly the quaternions transforms, hence resolving the "limited relevant material available online" issue.

Comment: Fair enough. However, it is unlikely that the OP is happy with that, since he even refuses to use glm for matrix math. Btw, your answer does not really answer his question. It is a step in the direction of a complete answer. Incomplete answers should mostly be comments. Keep that in mind for future posts. Welcome on StackOverflow :)